# Butter clarifying mixing mistake

Tags: oil, butter, ghee

During the making of clarified butter, I mistakenly mixed the oil and protiens in the pot with a wooden spoon. So I have an emulsion now. I was thinking, that the oil and the rest will separate anyway, but it is not the case, it is just an emulsion.

Is there a way, how to still separate the oil and the rest, so I can grab the oil and have clarified butter?

Comment: Sounds like magic butter to me. Warming it back up should make it split again if not... I've got no idea it's never happened to me before.

Comment: Agreed, it was an emulsion when you started and you broke it by heating. You re-emulsified, so you're just back where you started. If you melt it again, it should be fine.

Comment: after it become a emulsion , did you leave the pan in low heat to separate ?

Answer (score 1):

Try straining it out through a fine mesh strainer.

Answer (score -2):

The two comments above are correct in a certain way and incorrect in another way.  This happened to me 2 nights ago.  I made a desert that needed 4 cups of clarified butter for a specific desert.  I forgot what I was doing and last night when I got to making it I stirred it up after taking off the foam off the top, then saw the the white milky part and more junk.  I decided to reheat that one and start another one "just in case".  After melting, cooling and I thought everything was ready, boy was I wrong.  By the way, I was taught you do this on a low heat not fast and furious.  So after hours, the one that was messed up was still messed up and the "new one" was perfect" and I treated as such.  My desert came out perfect with those 4 cups of clarified butter.  The bad one I clean up some more, got some more milky stuff off and more foam and used it for another one of my other deserts.  It turned out great.  JUST AS A NOTE.  CLARIFIED BUTTER DOES NOT HAVE TO BE PUT IN THE FRIDGE, IT CAN STAY OUT AND IT DOES NOT BURN. MY ENTIRE LIFE MOST OF MY FAMILY HAVE USED THIS BUT... IT NEEDS TO BE GOOD QUALITY BUTTER, SWEET, UNSALTED BUTTER.